# What steps can I take to get Flask's render_template function to work in PythonAnywhere with a new project?

Tags: pythonanywhere, file-not-found

I am an experienced programmer, new to PythonAnywhere.
I setup a new project, and tried to do render_template("/home/myusername/mysite/templates/testFile.html")
I keep getting errors that the file is not found.
Tried "templates/testFile.html"
Tried "mysite/templates/testFile.html"
All of these attempts result in FileNotFound errors.
Any suggestions for me please?
Thanks in advance,
Victor

Answer (score 0):

try testFile.html without paths. If it does not work, you have an issue with flask not recognizing 'templates' folder.